# Use Redshift Copy command to do a merge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a process that iterates over input and spits out data to AWS Firehose that I have configured to upload to a redshift table I created. One problem is that sometimes the rows can be duplicated because the process needs to reevaluate data.
Something like:

```
Event_date, event_id, event_cost
2015-06-25, 123, 3
2015-06-25, 123, 4
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html

Looking there, I want to replace the old row with the new value, so something like:

```
insert into event_table_staging  
select event_date,event_id, event_cost from <s3 location>;

delete from event_table  
using event_table_staging  
where event_table.event_id = event_table_staging.event_id;

insert into target 
select * from event_table_staging;

delete from event_table_staging  
select * from event_table_staging;
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
Redshift columns: event_date,event_id,cost
copy event_table from <s3> 
(update event_table 
select c_source.event_date,c_source.event_id,c_source.cost from <s3 source> as c_source join event_table on c_source.event_id = event_table.event_id) 
CSV


copy event_table from <s3> 
(insert into event_table 
select c_source.event_date,c_source.event_id,c_source.cost from event_table left outer join<s3 source> as c_source join on c_source.event_id = event_table.event_id where c_source.event_id is NULL) 
CSV
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a merge directly from COPY.

However your initial approach can be wrapped in a transaction using a temp table to stage the load data for the best performance.

```sql
BEGIN
;
CREATE TEMP TABLE event_table_staging (
     event_date  TIMESTAMP  NULL
    ,event_id    BIGINT     NULL
    ,event_cost  INTEGER    NULL )
DISTSTYLE KEY
DISTKEY (event_id)
SORTKEY (event_id)
;
COPY event_table_staging  
FROM <s3 location>
COMPUDATE ON
;
UPDATE event_table  
SET    event_date = new.event_date
      ,event_cost = new.event_cost
FROM        event_table         AS trg
INNER JOIN  event_table_staging AS new
        ON  trg.event_id = new.event_id
WHERE COALESCE(trg.event_date,0) <> COALESCE(new.event_date,0)
  AND COALESCE(trg.event_cost,0) <> COALESCE(new.event_cost,0)
;
INSERT INTO event_table 
SELECT  event_date
       ,event_id  
       ,event_cost
FROM        event_table_staging AS new
LEFT JOIN   event_table         AS trg
       ON   trg.event_id = new.event_id
WHERE trg.event_id IS NULL
;
COMMIT
;
```

This approach actually performs amazingly well as long as you use a transaction and the total volume of updates is *relatively* low (single digit %). The only caveat is that your target will need to be `VACUUM`ed periodically - once a month is enough for us.

We do this hourly for several tables in the 100s of millions of rows range, i.e, 100s of millions of rows merged into 100s of millions of rows. User queries over the merged tables still perform well.

Comment: I cannot do this in one go, because the input is a Firehose Stream. I don't need hourly pulls, just EOD which is what I am going to configure a Lambda or Datapipeline job for ( still deciding in case I need event based execution)

Comment: What is the important part for performance? Why is using a transaction & a temp table important? If the staged table is decently large then I assume a temp table is not going to be in-memory (or distributed in-memory?) and will be on disk similar to a permanent table. I've been using AWS DMS tool to sync from Postgres to Redshift and the vast majority of usage on the RS cluster is DMS update jobs just trying to keep up. I note that it doesn't create properly typed stage tables though, everything is a wide string and the merge/upsert is done as a long case statement. It frequently lags to death

Comment: AWS DMS merges from a staging table using this pattern for every column: `"colname"= CASE WHEN "public"."awsdms_changesLONGUUIDHERE"."col1" IS NULL 
THEN "public"."target_table"."colname" 
WHEN "public"."awsdms_changesLONGUUIDHERE"."col1" = '<att_null>' 
THEN NULL 
ELSE CAST ( "public"."awsdms_changesLONGUUIDHERE"."col1" as INT4) END`  Note the magic value `<att_null>` for deleted data and the casting to the correct datatype from the wide string ( varchar(65535) ) columns in the staged table. This is not fast. It does separate inserts though, using a copy from S3 direct, which is fast.

Answer (score 2):

Redshift is optimize to handle massive amount of data in a cost efficient way, and you need to change some of the thinkings about the data and database that you have from other DB.

The main concept is that you shouldn't update data in Redshift. You should consider that data in Redshift as "Log". You can use functions as INSERT or UPDATE but they will limit the amount of data you can process dramatically.

You can handle duplicates in multiple ways:

- You can prevent from writing duplicates in the first place, by managing some in-memory lookup tables (for example in Redis on [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/)) of all the IDs you are processing and ignore a record if you already processed it
- You can keep duplicates inside Redshift and process these records using [WINDOW](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html) functions that will take only one of the records ([LAST_VALUE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html), for example).
- You can have the raw events in Redshift and do the aggregation in queries to the DB, instead of doing it as a preprocessing. This mode also gives flexibility in changing the way that you aggregate the data. Redshift can be very fast with these aggregation, and there is little need for pre-aggregation.

If you still want to have "clean" and aggregated data in Redshift, you can [UNLOAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) that data with some SQL query with the right aggregation or a WINDOW function, delete the old table and COPY the data back into Redshift.

Comment: Thanks, I added an Identity column so I can differentiate between event_id's. I will create a separate table that only stores the results of the latest updates.

Comment: I really do not agree that `UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`DELETE` are unilaterally bad in Redshift. Those commands are fully supported and well documented. We merge **many millions** of rows every hour in Redshift using these commands with no issue.

Comment: Also doing an `UNLOAD` and reload to the *same database* is completely unnecessary. `INSERT INTO` and `CREATE TABLE … AS` exist for just this purpose.

Comment: I am not going to do an unload in this case, or the window functions. I do plan on using ElastiCache for the stream side. My solution is going to stream into a staging table with an autoid column. Since I distkey off of event_date, I'm going create a separate load step that does the actual EOD merge, that will grab the latest values and cleans up historical data.

Comment: I just realized my solution is closer to yours...do I unaccept and accept yours?